# For what $z$ does this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

I am given the following power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n}+z^{-n}}{n^2}$$
My attempt:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n}+z^{-n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}+1}{n^2z^{2n}}\cdot z^n$$

I then tried to solve for the radius using $z_n$ but can't find a solution. Can someone explain me how to get the radius of convergence and then how to calculate the points to which this series converges? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a power series? To me a power series have this form $$a=\sum a_k X^k$$

Comment: I think so atleast it appears on a bunch of exercises about power series and their radius of convergence. I can do the others because they are in the form you mentioned but this one i cant solve

Comment: (with the typo corrected) this is a (formal) Laurent series, and if $|z| \ne 1$ then $|z^n + z^{-n}| \sim |z|^n$. For $|z|=1$, you have to use the summation by parts : $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} z^n =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nz^n +\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(\frac1{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})\sum_{m=1}^nz^m$

Comment: Shouldn´t a Laurent series start in negative infinity?

Comment: Sorry but are formal power series any different from normal power series. I was trying to change the series so that i could put it in a format where i could calcutate the radius and from there the z to which it converges

Comment: You have misstated the problem, with $i$ and $n$ and other things. State it precisely please

Comment: Sorry about that i fixed it now

Comment: It's not a power series, so there's no reason to expect it to have a "radius of convergence". It converges if, and only if, $|z|=1$.

Comment: Are you still here, Pedro?

Comment: yeah sorry had somethings that took me some time what makes you believe it is not a power series? And if it is a normal series how can i see here it converges normally with other series they either converge or they not rigth?

Comment: If you want to be sure that I see a comment addressed to me, Pedro, you have to include @Gerry in it. It's not a power series because, by definition, a power series only has nonnegative powers of $z$. And I've told you when it converges, and when it doesn't, so what is your problem?

Comment: @Gerry Sorry kinda new to this. I thinks there are some power series with negative powers of z the laurent series for example. You got the same answer as my book could you explain me how you manage to find it. I kind of thought that a series that is not a power series would either converge or diverge not being dependent of where. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|>1$, then $$\left|{z^n+z^{-n}\over n^2}\right|\ge\left|{z^n\over n^2}\right|-\left|{z^{-n}\over n^2}\right|>1$$ for large $n$ (since $|z^n/n^2|\to\infty$ and $z^{-n}/n^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$), so the series diverges (a necessary condition for $\sum a_n$ to converge is $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$).

If $|z|<1$, then $$\left|{z^n+z^{-n}\over n^2}\right|\ge\left|{z^{-n}\over n^2}\right|-\left|{z^n\over n^2}\right|>1$$ for large $n$ (since $|z^{-n}/n^2|\to\infty$ and $z^n/n^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$), so the series diverges.

If $|z|=1$, then the series converges, by comparison to $\sum2n^{-2}$.